# Sortdescriptor causes replaceObjectAtIndex not to work anymore

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nssortdescriptor

Following code works fine the first time it is called. But if i remove the sorting then it works even past the first time. But as soon as the sorting is enabled i am not able to replace a value in the keywordscontroller. (keywordscontroller is a NSArrayController)

```
[newkwmutabledict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[kwmutabledict valueForKey:@"keyword"]] forKey: @"keyword"];
[newkwmutabledict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newnum] forKey: @"order"];

[keywordscontroller.content replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedRow withObject:newkwmutabledict] ;

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
[keywordscontroller setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[singleKeywordTable reloadData];
```

Basically the last line of code causes the third line of code not to work anymore. Why?

--EDIT --

My guess is that keywordscontroller.content has a different ordering that keywordscontroller.arrangedobjects. But if I try to replace something in arrangedobjects it fails with the message `[_NSControllerArrayProxy replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

as requested here is the log of the araycontroller:

```
content = (
    {
    keyword = female;
    order = "1.000000";
},
    {
    keyword = hat;
    order = "2.000000";
},
  //..
    {
    keyword = "looking at camera";
    order = "41.000000";
}
```

Comment: "i am not able to replace a value" -- error message? exception? invalid index?   What is the signature of "i am not able to replace?"  It doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: it just does nothing. no error messages, nothing in the log, just nothign.. the value in "order" stays the same.

Comment: my guess is that keywordscontroller.content has a different ordering that kwywordscontroller.arrangedobjects. but if I try to replace something in arrangedobjects it fails with the message `[_NSControllerArrayProxy replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance `

Comment: What is the output of keywordscontroller.content? NSLog(@"content = %@", keywordscontroller.content);

Comment: You're using bindings for this table and AC-- binding to a table column?  That would create a sortDescriptors binding to the column.  setSortDescriptors might then do something weird.

Comment: Yes I am using bindings. but I disabled the "create sort descriptors" checkbox to avoid trouble. @JordiKroon will post the output in a moment in the main post.

Comment: all i want to do is to update the value "order" of the selected row to the new value and then sort the table based on that value. maybe i am doing it wrong.